# Как добавить в регулярку /\ []?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

подскажите пожалуйста как добавить в данную регулярку данные символы чтобы они игнорировались в конце

[
]
\
/

https://regex101.com/r/gSHSsW/2

Comment: Это для теста или будет потом в бою? Не проще тогда сделать `@[a-z0-9]+`

Comment: Символьные классы знаков пунктуации никто не отменял: [`~@[^\s\pP]+~`](https://regex101.com/r/gSHSsW/4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в конец `\/\[-\]` и заэкранируйте дефис, чтобы он не воспринимался как диапазон символов:

```perl
@[^\h!@#$%^&*()?,><.{}~`'|"+\-\/\[-\]]+
```

где:

- `\-` — соответствует символу `-` буквально,
- `\/` — соответствует символу `/` буквально,
- `\[-\]` — диапазон символов от `[` до `]`, в который входят `[` (U+005B), `\` (U+005C) и `]` (U+005D).

Comment: А дефис разве нельзя точно так же экранировать \- ? Я просто не помню.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, можно и так написать.

Comment: Просто должно быть единообразие, не надо использовать лишние сущности без необходимости :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, что-то поторопился с написанием сообщения, отредактировал свой ответ.

Comment: Символьные классы знаков пунктуации никто не отменял: [`~@[^\s\pP]+~`](https://regex101.com/r/gSHSsW/4)

Comment: @Эдуард, ваше выражение не подойдёт, оно не исключает символы: `$`, `^`, `+`, `<`, `>` и некоторые другие.

Comment: Можно дополнить символьный класс: [`~@[^\s\pP\pS]+~`](https://regex101.com/r/gSHSsW/7)